# Мульти тач как в Piano Tile

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Каким методом реализовать данную функцию? Если touch.counts, то отслеживает только количество нажатий. Мне нужно, чтобы каждый тач работал отдельно. OnMouseDown или UI buttons не подходят, т.к если одновременно нажать, то работает только одна, а и button работает только когда отпустить ее.
PS: Игра не пиано, просто самый подходящий пример.

Comment: оффтоп: я так понимаю, что мультитач (на андроиде) имеет ограничения и толком жмякнуть трезвучие не получится, а уж все эти изыски с семптами вообще никак. (

Comment: мне много одновременных тачей не надо, всего лишь 2, и отследить, каждый тач должен выполнять свою функцию. Например: держу один тач, он делает свою функцию и не отпуская нажимаю второй, и так же свою функцию выполняет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [Input.touches](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html), в документации также описан пример работы. Информации, предоставляемой классом [Touch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html) должно быть достаточно (например на ее основе, вы сможете сделать Raycast, чтобы понять куда пришелся тач по экрану)